# How install both Python32 and Python33 on OS X for testing with tox?

Tags: python

I'm adding Python 3.x support to my open-source project and want to add both Py32 and Py33 test environments to my tox.ini. I already have Py26 and Py27 tox environments that work fine and I just installed Python 3.3 from homebrew and got the Py33 tox environment working nicely.

The problem seems to be that homebrew doesn't have an obvious way to install both 3.3 and 3.2 and a somewhat extended Googling did not yield an answer.

What's the best way to do this that won't lead me into trouble further down the road? I'm happy to build from source if that's the best solution, have done that before with good success but don't want to break out the axe if a pocket knife will get the job done :)

I'm running OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem seems to be that homebrew doesn't have an obvious way to install both 3.3 and 3.2 and a somewhat extended Googling did not yield an answer.

**— Try the following solution to install multiple Python 3.x versions with `brew`:**

1. Make sure you don't have any Python 3.x installed:

   `brew uninstall python3`
2. Then `cd` into your brew directory, this is `/usr/local` normally:

   `cd /usr/local`
3. Then list all the available Python 3.x versions in Homebrew:

   `brew versions python3`
4. Then follow installation instructions for required Python versions from [here](https://gist.github.com/Bouke/11261620).

Comment: Sweet! This gets it done :)  Now I can use tox to test with all of Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4 :)

Comment: `brew versions` has been removed

Answer (score 8):

The [installation instructions](https://gist.github.com/Bouke/11261620) referenced by @dimitry-cheremushkin have been changed and recommend using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) instead. Tox and Pyenv can be used together like this:

First we ensure we have `pyenv` installed:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install pyenv
```

Then we install all the needed python versions with `pyenv`. This might take time. See [python.org/downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/) for available versions.

```
$ pyenv install 2.6.9 && pyenv ... && pyenv install 3.5.0
```

In the directory of our setup.py, let us run `pyenv local ...` as below. It will create `.python-version` file that stores the versions to be used.

```
$ pyenv local 2.6.9 2.7.10 3.2.6 3.3.6 3.4.3 3.5.0
```

So, `pyenv` installed the Python distributions to a dir `~/.pyenv/shims`. To let them to be found instead default Python, the dir must be prepended to the PATH environment variable. Even though more [permanent solutions](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) exist, the following [does the trick for one terminal session](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#neckbeard-configuration):

```
$ eval "$(pyenv init -)"
$ echo $PATH
/Users/myname/.pyenv/shims:/usr/bin:...
```

The following [has been recommended](http://tbb.co/using-tox-and-pyenv-for-testing-and-development/) to be run to ensure the shims have correct packages:

```
$ pyenv rehash
```

Now, let us assume the following `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py26,py27,py30,py31,py32,py33,py34,py35
[testenv]
deps=
    nose2
    unittest2
commands=nose2
```

Finally we can run `tox` in all the environments:

```
$ tox
...
py26: commands succeeded
py27: commands succeeded
py30: commands succeeded
py31: commands succeeded
py32: commands succeeded
py33: commands succeeded
py34: commands succeeded
py35: commands succeeded
congratulations :)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what `.python-version` is for. Why is it needed? Should it be committed to version control?

Comment: @Flimm The `.python-version` tells `pyenv` which python versions it should make available in the current directory and to which exact versions the shorthands like `python` or `python3` should refer to. The first line defines the version to be used when `python` is called. If you expect the other developers to use pyenv to test the code in the repository, then I think you should commit `.python-version` too.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org):

```
$ sudo port install python34 python35
[...]
$ python3.4 -V
Python 3.4.6
$ python3.5 -V
Python 3.5.3
```

You can also select which version should be used when running `python3`:

```
$ port select python3
Available versions for python3:
    none
    python34 (active)
    python35
$ sudo port select python3 python35
Password:
Selecting 'python35' for 'python3' succeeded. 'python35' is now active.
```